# Javascript DOM detect elements style change (Without JQUERY)

Tags: javascript, styles, dom-events

I developing a javascript application and i need to detect id="mydiv" 's any style changes without JQUERY.

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").addEventListener("WHATISANYCHANGESEVENTNAME", function() {
     alert("change detected");
})
```

How can i do that.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FMutationObserver)

```js
let observer = new MutationObserver((mutations, observer) => {
    mutations.map( m => console.log(m.target.style.cssText) );
});

observer.observe(mydiv, {attributes: true});


// TEST which change background
function changeBg(e) {  
  e.target.style.background = '#'+(Math.random()*2**24|0).toString(16); // random color
}
```

```css
.foo { width: 100px; height: 100px; background: yellow }
```

```html
<div id="mydiv" class="foo" onclick="changeBg(event)">clik on me</div>
```

Comment: Note, MutationObserver's are terribly slow and their handlers an usual source of "event storms" (observer's handler triggering other mutation events). If at all possible, you should use programmatic callbacks/events if you control the code that triggers the change.